# Git on WSL commands fail despite permissions seeming fine

Tags: permissions, git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Since upgrading Windows 10 to version 1903 (build 18362), I am unable to run git commands in WSL that would need to write files, including `git add` and `git stash`, in repositories that are on mounted network drives. Git complains with

> error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects

This also affects newly created repositories right after initializing them.

The obvious solution of fixing permissions does not help: my user account owns the .git directory and everything in it, all of which has rwx permissions in WSL. The user account also has full permissions on the Windows side. I can `touch .git/objects/test_file` just fine.

Running in an admin session did not help either.

What also seems relevant is that

- with Git for Windows (not WSL) I am able to run those commands in the same repositories
- in repositories on a local drive, I can also run the commands with WSL Git

`mount -l` shows the network drive mounted as
H: on /mnt/h type drvfs (rw,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off)

What could I be missing? I have read about several possible causes, including Windows Defender settings and self-reverting read-only attributes on Windows, but none of them seem to be the problem here.

Comment: Seems like this issue has been fixed but is still open.  [git: "fatal: fsync error Permission denied"](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3556).  The issue existed at one time on the 1903 branch.  I suspect the problem is the mount itself.  I personally would attempt to use the alias solution though.

Comment: Use `fmask`,`dmask` or `umask` permissions in `wsl.conf` file. More [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/automatically-configuring-wsl/).

Comment: @Biswapriyo Are the *mask options not used to change default permissions to something other than WSL's default 777? How would reducing the permissions help? I tried it to see if those options have other side effects - problem persists.

Comment: @Ramhound `alias git=git.exe` is what I do for now. It's a horrible workaround though.